# Laravel 4 and Eloquent: retrieving all records and all related records

Tags: orm, laravel, foreign-key-relationship, eloquent

I have two classes: `Artist` and `Instrument`. Each `Artist` can play one or more `Instrument`s. And each `Instrument` can be assigned to one or more `Artist`s. So, I've set up the following Classes:

**Artist.php**

```
public function instruments() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Instrument');
}
```

**Instrument.php**

```
public function artists() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\Artist');
}
```

Then I have three database tables:

```
artists: id, firstname, lastname, (timestamps)
instruments: id, name
artist_instrument: id, artist_id, instrument_id
```

I'm able to successfully retrieve a **one** artist and their associated instruments like so:

**ArtistController.php**

```
$artist = Artist::find($artist_id);
$instruments = $artist->instruments()->get();
return \View::make('artists')->with('artists', $artists)->with('instruments', $instruments);
```

**I have 3 questions:**

1. In my view, I can output the `$artist` like:

   ```
   {{ $artist->firstname }}
   ```

   and I can iterate through `$instruments` like:

   ```
   @foreach ($instruments as $instrument)
       <h2>{{ $instrument->name }}</h2>
   @endforeach
   ```

   but is it possible to iterate over `$artist` (I know there's only one — see #2) and for each `$artist` iterate over their `$instruments`?
2. In my controller, how would I get **all** artists and for each of those their associated instruments with the end goal of iterating through them in my view as described in #1.
3. Is it possible to only retrieve specific columns in the above example of `ArtistController.php`? I've tried this:

   ```
   $artist = Artist::where('id', $artist_id)->get('firstname');
   $instruments = $artist->instruments()->get();
   return \View::make('artists')->with('artists', $artists)->with('instruments', $instruments);
   ```

   but I get an error saying `Collection::instruments()` is undefined.

I'm assuming there's something not right in my model relationships. I've also tried defining my relationship in **Artist.php** with a `hasMany` (I think it makes more sense to say "Each Artist hasMany Instruments", but that gives me an error because it's expecting a table named `artists_instruments` and it's also trying to retrieve columns that wouldn't exists in that table (like `name`).

Comment: Try including your relationship key for Artist in your ->get('firstname'). ( I'm assuming it would be 'id' like this: ->get('id', 'firstname') )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your model relationships are fine.

**Controller:**

```php
$artists = Artist::with('instruments')->get();

return \View::make('artists')->withArtists($artists);
```

**View:**

```html
@foreach ($artists as $artist)

    <h1>{{ $artist->firstname }}</h1>

    @foreach ($artist->instruments as $instrument)

        <h2>{{ $instrument->name }}</h2>

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Comment: I just stumbled upon the answer as you posted and this is exactly what I did. Thank you!

Comment: One more thing (and I can post this as a separate question if it makes sense) how would I specify the columns to retrieve if I didn't want to retrieve all of them? I've tried using `select()` in various places, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: @tptcat - that should definitely be a separate question.

Comment: The followup question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737547/laravel-and-eloquent-specifying-columns-in-when-retrieving-related-items