# Laravel and Eloquent: Specifying columns in when retrieving related items

Tags: select, laravel, relationship, eloquent

**This is a followup post to:** [Laravel 4 and Eloquent: retrieving all records and all related records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735011/laravel-4-and-eloquent-retrieving-all-records-and-all-related-records)

The solution given works great:

```
$artists = Artist::with('instruments')->get();
return \View::make('artists')->withArtists($artists);
```

It also works with just:

```
$artists = Artist::get();
```

Now I'm trying to specify the exact columns to return for both tables. I've tried using `select()` in both the statement above and in my Class, like this:

**ArtistController.php**

```
$artists = Artist::select('firstname', 'lastname', 'instruments.name')->get();
```

or:

```
$artists = Artist::with(array('instruments' => function($query) {
    $query->select('name');
}))->get();
```

(as suggested [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852927/get-specific-columns-using-with-function-in-laravel-eloquent) and while this doesn't throw an error, it also doesn't limit the columns to only those specified)

or in **Artist.php**:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Instrument')->select(['name']);
```

How would I go about getting *just* the `firstname` and `lastname` column from the `artists` table and the `name` column from `instruments` table?

Comment: Your problem is that you have to load the primary key and the foreign key. Otherwise the ORM can't load your relationships.

Comment: @JosephSilber Your comment helped me! So, live happy in the knowledge that you've helped at least one individual with their development! :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what I was thinking. I think working on this so long got me cross-eyed.

Anyhow, I looked into this a lot more and searched for answers and finally posted an issue on GitHub.

The bottom line is this is **not** possible as of Laravel v4.1.

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/2679

<strike>This solved it:</strike>

**Artists.php**

```
public function instruments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Instrument', 'id');
}
```

Note that I changed this to a `hasMany` from a `belongsToMany` which makes more sense to me as a musicians (or `Artist`) would have many `Instrument`s they play and an `Instrument` could belong to many `Artist`s (which I also alluded to in my previous questions referenced above). I also had to specify `'id'` column in my model which tells the ORM that `instrument.id` matches `artist_instrument.id`. That part confuses me a bit because I thought the order for `hasMany` was `foreign_key`, `primary_key`, but maybe I'm thinking about it backwards. If someone can explain that a bit more I'd appreciate it.

Anyhow, the second part of the solution...

In **ArtistsController.php**, I did this:

```
$artists = Artist::with(array(
    'instruments' => function($q) {
        $q->select('instruments.id', 'name');
    })
)->get(array('id', 'firstname', 'lastname'));
```

That gives me exactly what I want which is a collection of Artists that contains only the `firstname` and `lastname` columns from the `artists` table and the `name` column for each of the instruments they play from the `instruments`.

Comment: "Limiting the columns on a belongsToMany relationship is not currently supported."

Answer (score 2):

```php
$artists = Artist::with(array('instruments' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('id', 'name');
}))->get('id', 'firstname', 'lastname');
```

Comment: This throws an error saying the `id` columns are ambiguous. If I do this: `instruments.id` and `artists.id` then it doesn't fail, but it doesn't limit the columns. In this case though, `instruments.id` is a foreign key of `instrument_id` in `artist_instrument` and `artists.id` is a foreign key of `artist_id` in `artist_instrument`.